# stash Pull Request Builder Plugin

Tags: pull-request, bitbucket-server

Has any one used stash builder plugin.Its documentation says that it  adds some environment variables in to the build environment but if i echo them,they all are empty

```
echo "${sourceBranch}"
echo "${targetBranch}"
echo "${sourceRepositoryOwner}"
echo "${sourceRepositoryName}"
echo "${pullRequestId}"
echo "${destinationRepositoryOwner}"
echo "${destinationReposotryName}"
echo "${pullRequestTitle}"
echo "${sourceCommitHash}"
```

This plugin is doing nothing for me.Here is my configuration
I am selecting git as SCM [poll scm is not selected]

```
RepositoryUrl:ssh://git@stash-eng.abc.com:7999/mytool/my_tools_demo.git
Refspec:\+refs/pull-requests/*:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*
Branch Specifier:-origin/pr/${pullRequestId}/from
```

Then i mark the checkbox "Stash Pull Requests Builder"
and below is the value for diff fields

```
Cron:H/2 * * * *
Stash Host:stash-eng.abc.com
Stash Credentials:..........
Project:mytool
Repository Name:my_tools_demo
```

Still its doing nothing.Nor i ma seeing any thing related to plugin in logs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this plugin in my company and it's working well.

In my Stash environment, all the project names are in uppercase.

If you have the same kind of project name, can you try to use them in uppercase? (in the Stash Pull Requests Builder section)

If you have one open pull request, can you try to add this comment to trigger a new Jenkins build?

```
test this please
```

This is a magic comment to trigger a new PR build from Stash.

Comment: No Luck for me this error git config --local --remove-section credential # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/pr/${pullRequestId}/from^{commit} # timeout=10...
it seems that none of the environmnet variable is being set by this plugin and thats why pullRequestId is empty.

Comment: i found error INFO: Fetch PullRequests.
Jan 14, 2016 9:47:01 PM stashpullrequestbuilder.stashpullrequestbuilder.stash.StashApiClient getRequest
SEVERE: Failing to get response from Stash PR GET 
Jan 14, 2016 9:47:01 PM hudson.triggers.Trigger checkTriggers
WARNING: stashpullrequestbuilder.stashpullrequestbuilder.StashBuildTrigger.run() failed for hudson.maven.MavenModuleSet@591748[ci_demo_verify_pr]
java.lang.RuntimeException: Didn't get a 200 response from Stash PR GET! Response; 'Not Found' with message; <html lang="en">
<head>
my stash  is running on https

Comment: My configuration is using a SSH Git URL. My Jenkins user public key is registered on all the Stash projects. Can you have a try with this solution?

Comment: After changing my project name to capital letters it worked. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same issue with Jenkins 2.7

According to below issue tracking in Github

https://github.com/nemccarthy/stash-pullrequest-builder-plugin/issues/84

it is fixed in one of the branch

https://github.com/eirikwang/stash-pullrequest-builder-plugin/tree/newChange

And will be merged into master soon..